# manipulating Gaussian distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

I have a joint distribution which factorises as follows:

$$
q(w) = \prod_{i=1}^{N} t_i
$$

where each $t_i$ is a 3-dimensional normal distribution which some mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\mathbf{I}\sigma_i$ where $I$ is the identity and $\sigma_i$ is the precision which is also three dimensional to have anisotropic behaviour. Now, if I want to combine this into one big multivariate distribution ($q(w)$) which is of dimension $N \times 3$ is it simply a matter of stacking up the mean and sigma vectors. I think, yes, as the factorization implies independence but wanted to check.

Comment: What do you mean by stacking up? The joint pdf of two independent univariate normals with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ doesn't have a mean at $\mu_1 +\mu_2$ or at $\mu_1\mu_2$. If you mean either multiplication or addition by 'stacking up' then you will most probably be wrong.

Comment: No, I just meant representing it in a vector form with components $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$.....$\mu_n$. You are right, I abused the language there.

Comment: Ah yes. Then the answer is yes. The covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is then given by $\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot \mathbf{\sigma}^T$ where $\mathbf{\sigma}$ is the vector obtained when stacking up the variance vectors $\mathbf{\sigma}_i$ of the individual 3-dimensional normal distributions.

Comment: But on the other hand, we cannot conclude independence between the 3 dimensions within each $t$, so I don't think we can assume independence between all dimensions in the big multivariate distribution.

Comment: You are absolutely right about this. This independence between the components of the $i$th element is a problem but I am not sure what to do about it anyway!

Comment: How would you 'stack up' the covariance matrices $\Sigma_i$ into one big $\Sigma$? I guess you should just take the covaraince matrix as I defined it above and then replace all $3\times3$ submatrices along the diagonal with the covariance matrices of the individual $t$'s. Still I cannot verify if this approach is correct.

Comment: If the covariance matrices has off diagonal terms, I think it is more complicated as the sigmas will mix and the matrix will get dense, I think.

Comment: I'm sorry. What I supposed to say was an all-zero matrix with all $3\times3$ submatrices replaces by the covariance matrices of each $t_i$.

Comment: However, I think I have reason to believe this approach i incorrect. Let's simplify the problem. Suppose $N=2$ and each $t_i$ is 2-dimensional. Let's examine the example in which the variables of these 2-dimensional distributions are perfectly correlated. As such they follow a univariate distribution over a diagonal line in their respective spaces. When we multiply these distributions we get a bivariate normal in a plane which lies askew in the 4D-space of $q$.

Comment: You can imagine that it has a slope $\neq 0$ between two dimensions from the separate $t_i$'s, which means that there is a non-zero covariance between them, meaning that we cannot construct the covariance matrix in the above manner ('stacking diagonally'). But I find imagination in 4D quite difficult, so maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found the answer in [this](http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-gaussians.pdf) PDF and my hunch was correct. It reads:

More generally, one can show that an n-dimensional Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and diagonal covariance matrix is the same as a collection of n independent Gaussian random variables with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i^{2}$ respectively on page 4.